# How to iterate over MethodCall object to get the parameters

Tags: java, android, flutter

I have some specific android code and I invoke some commands in android with parameters.

This is the android code that I use for now to check for a specific argument name, and if it exists, to fetch it:

```java
@Override public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
    if (call.method.equals("[METHOD_NAME]")) {
        if (call.hasArgument("[ARGUMENT_NAME]")) {
            final String paramVal = call.argument("[ARGUMENT_NAME]");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how can I iterate over the object to get all parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can iterate it over. This is how you will do it.

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = call.arguments();
Log.i("MyTag", "value 1 = " + list.get(0).get("key1")); // prints Apple
Log.i("MyTag", "value 2 = " + list.get(1).get("key2")); // prints Ball
```

In dart, let's say this is my implementation.

```
MethodChannel("my_method_channel").invokeMethod("METHOD_NAME", [
  {"key1": "Apple"},
  {"key2": "Ball"},
]);
```